# How to connect your pytest container to appium container running in same docker machine using --link command

Tags: docker, appium, pytest

I am running appium in a container. I am able to run my tests also in a container. Both are running in same docker machine but I am not able to point my tests to appium container. I tried running tests with --link but not working.

running my appium container with command:

```
docker run -d -p 32769:4723 --privileged --name appium_server_v1 appium/appium
```

exposing port 32769 for pytest to consume

using host = 0.0.0.0 and port = 32769 in my desired capabilities

I am running my pytest tests using command:

```
docker run -it --link appium_server_v1:appium/appium --name uitests_v1 uitests
```

uitests is my image which contain my tests

I have build it with a Dockerfile whose contents are:

```
FROM python:alpine3.7
WORKDIR .
COPY . .
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["pytest"]
```

I am using mac os

I am able to run the tests when my tests are running in local and appium server is running in container in a docker machine. I am using HOST = 192.168.99.100 and PORT = 32769

```
=========================================================================================== test session starts ============================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.2, pytest-4.3.0, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.9.0
rootdir: /, inifile:
plugins: metadata-1.8.0, html-1.20.0
collecting ...
```

These are pytest logs it does not proceed after this and nothing appears in appium server logs

I am using a real device with a host and port for adb connect via appium conatiner. I am expecting my tests to run on the real device which is running when I run my test from local but not running when I dockerise my tests.

Answer (score 0):

`link` option is [deprecated](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/). You should create a network and connect containers to it :

```
docker network create mynet

docker container run -d -p 32769:4723 --privileged --network=mynet --name appium_server_v1 appium/appium

docker container run -it --network=mynet --name uitests_v1 uitests
```

And then you can connect to your appium server using `appium_server_v1:4723` from within the `uitests_v1` container.

Comment: Tried this still facing the same issue, ran both containers with network 'mynet'. tried with port 4723 as well as 32769. what should be the IP of appium_server_v1 wrt to uitests_v1? I am guessing it is 0.0.0.0 only. Is this an IP issue?

Comment: You never make outbound connections to 0.0.0.0 (it is a magic IPv4 address for "everywhere").  You should be able to use the other container's `--name` as an ordinary DNS name; don't worry about its IP address.

Comment: Use the container-internal port (4723).  It doesn't specifically need to be "published" or "exposed".

Answer (score 0):

the solution @michalk told worked. I have edited my docker file a little bit

## Use an official Python runtime as a parent image

FROM python:alpine3.7

## Set the working directory to /app

WORKDIR /app

## Set the working directory to /app

COPY . /app

## Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt

RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

## Make port 80 available to the world outside this container

EXPOSE 80

## Run pytest when the container launches

CMD ["pytest","/app/"]

and I have removed all the .pyc file using the command to make the tests run properly in the docker container

```
find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm -f {} \;
```